# Dual boot RetroPie and Windows XP on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: windows

I have a raspberry pi 3 model b, and I currently use it for RetroPie, and I know there's a thing that lets me dual boot on it.

But my question is, would my pi handle WinXP as an emergency back-up workstation for drawing on Clip Studio Paint?
just been thinking it would be a good measure in case my computer meets it's doom somehow.

And quick fyi: My pi does have a fan and heatsinks to ensure heating problems don't ensure (I think).

Comment: what yor Pi does not have, is a CPU that is capable of running winXP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to execute different installations on the SD Card using programs like NOOBS or better PINN instead, berryboot, U-boot etc. to start them. But the installations must be compiled for the ARM processor (**armhf**) of the Raspberry Pi. This is the case for example with Raspbian but not with Windows XP. It is compiled for intel or amd processors (**iX86**) so you cannot run it on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: An emulator could potentially perform a mapping from x86 to ARM, although I guess it would be horribly slow.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late reply.

You can use berry boot to create two different poses to boot, and install qemu on one, get xp working on a VM, get it to boot on startup and then it should have a dual boot of xp and raspbian.

Xp will be slow though, because you are emualting x86, and xp likes 1gb of ram.

Comment: How do you do that? It would be nice if you could elaborate your answer a bit about the setup.